# installing Ubuntu on an Alienware M17Xr 4 laptop

Tags: laptop, alienware

I'm trying to install ubuntu on an alienware M17X r4, when I get to the install screen it is hard to describe but it's like 4 versions of the same screen but in pink and with a lot of lines.

This is with my Nvidia GTS 660M turned on, not my Intel Graphics, my computer has a switch to choose between them.

Comment: Install with Intel then. After you install you can solve this issue using Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During install, I would switch the the Intel Graphics. Once you have it installed you can go back and install the drivers for the Nvidia card.

Comment: OK once i get everything re downloaded and my Hard drives petitioned again i will try this